# Cannot login through SSH on Sakura's VPS. Operation timed out

Tags: ssh, vps, timeout

I am trying loging in to vps ubuntu server.

But I connot connect it. I get an this error.
`Operation timed out`

Server is running.↓
[server is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxUg1.png)

Sakura's VNC console is like this↓

[vnc console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64y4S.png)

I have no idea to fix it.

Please tell me how to fix it.
Thank to you.

Comment: What us the output of "iptables -vnl"?  Alternatively does "iptables -I INPUT -p tcp dport 22 -j ACCEPT" let you in?

Comment: Is this a completely new server?

Comment: Sorry for late. Thank you yor replying.
I resolved this issue. from VNC console.
I will write that how to resolve this problem in the future.